# Pass json to Vue component and loop

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vue-component

This is the expected output:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="title">Title 1</div>
        <div class="text"><p>Text 1</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="title">Title 2</div>
        <div class="text"><p>Text 2</p></div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

This is my PHP file:

```
// Contains HTML markup
$array = [
    ['title' => 'Title 1', 'text' => '<p>Text 1<\/p>'],
    ['title' => 'Title 2', 'text' => '<p>Text 2<\/p>'],
    ...
];

<div class="container" data-content="'.json_encode($array).'">
    <list-item v-for="item in list" v-bind:list-prop="item" v-bind:key ="item.title"></list-item>
</div>
```

And this is my JavaScript file:

```
var containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
if(containers.length > 0) {
    for(var i=0; i<containers.length; i++)
        buildList(containers[i]);
}

function buildList(el) {

    Vue.component('list-item', {
        props: ['listProp'],
        template: '<div class="wrapper"><div class="title">{{ listProp.title }}</div><div class="text">{{ listProp.text }}</div></div>'
    });

    var container = new Vue({
        el: el,
        data: {
            list: JSON.parse(el.dataContent)
        }
    });
}
```

I'm getting an error `Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse` I'm obviously doing something wrong but I'm not sure where. Would love to know if there are better ways to achieve this. I read answers using `:prop` but I don't know how to implement it in my case.

Comment: You get an immediate upvote for _"This is the expected output"_. So refreshing!

Comment: You cannot encode JSON into an HTML attribute, at least not without encoding the quotes. Your resulting HTML will look like `data-content="["title":"Title 1",..."`. Notice the problem with the quotes?

Comment: You appear to also be defining your component every time you call `buildList`

Comment: I figured, but somehow removing it from the function causes an error. How should I address this?

Answer (score 0):

I REALLY hate this suggestion, but here is something you could do without creating a simple REST API with PHP. Then, once you have this object on the window object, you can then reference it within your Vue.js code.

```html
// Contains HTML markup
<?php
$array = [
    ['title' => 'Title 1', 'text' => '<p>Text 1<\/p>'],
    ['title' => 'Title 2', 'text' => '<p>Text 2<\/p>'],
    ...
];
?>
<script>
  const titles = <?php echo $array; ?>
</script>
<div class="container">
    <list-item v-for="item in list" v-bind:list-prop="item" v-bind:key ="item.title"></list-item>
</div>
```